# put attribute at runtime during marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

After object to XML conversion using JAXB for existing POJOs I am getting the XML as:

```
<USER>
    <FIELDNAME>FirstName</FIELDNAME>
    <FIELDVALUE>Michael</FIELDVALUE>
    <FIELDID>001</FIELDID>
</USER>
```

But, as per the requirements it has to be like:

```
<USER>
    <FIRSTNAME ID="001">Michael</FIRSTNAME>
</USER>
```

Hence I modified POJOs as:

User.java

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name="USER")
    public class User 
    {
        @XmlVariableNode("fieldName")
        List<Field> field;
        //   getter/setter
    }
```

Field.java

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Field 
    {
        @XmlTransient
        public String fieldName;
        @XmlValue
        public String fieldValue;
        //   getter/setter
    }
```

And getting XML somewhat expected(as below) but not exactly:

```
<USER>
    <FIRSTNAME>Michael</FIRSTNAME>
</USER>
```

The above mentioned scenario is too simple I know but apart from *FIRSTNAME* there can be many elements depends upon the situation.
Now, how and what should I do to get the *ID* attribute for *FIRSTNAME*. where I need to declare the ID property or something other that can help me to get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@XmlAttribute` for that.
Do you intend on auto-generating the ID?

Example:

```
@XmlAttribute(name="ID")
private String id;
```